# android gridview or listview

Tags: android, listview, gridview

I'm trying to develop a 3 column gridview and I need advices. 
2 columns data coming from database and 3rd column is a delete button.
Data is stored in sqlite and columns like following;

1-Name: name of the product(string)
2-Type(Picture): type picture of the product, there are 10 pictures(type1.gif,type2.gif,...type10.gif)
3-Delete: It is a button or imagebutton which will delete the data from sqlite db.

Can you give a sample project link or tell me which one is better for performance and less code, gridview or listview?

Comment: No we will not. do your stuff on your own and if u run into issues in "your code" then come back on SO with question. start here http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/

Comment: Bhanu I don't want you from the code, read my question first before. I already read lots of tutorials like myyong.com but I'm not sure which one is the best for performance because in most of tutorials they create lots of objects(one byone in a cursor) so I believe this is not correct there should be another way. If you don't want to share don't bother people writing this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

As a suggestion,

you can create a list view, there you need to create a custom layout for the each row. This custom layout consist with textview (product name) ,  imageview (for the image)  and a button. Once you click a certain button , you can get the product name/id from the respective model and delete the corresponding row from the database.

Use view holder patterns for this, and use lazy loader or similar technique to load the rows into the list (if total rows count is much larger).

This would be a the one of easy/efficient way to do this and you can easily find the code from google.